# Jackson polymorphic collection serialization in multiple steps to avoid type-erasure

Tags: java, jackson

I have polymorphic objects in a project. I also have a webservice that requires objects in JSON. I wish to store the objects to be sent in a Map to have them later serialized with Jackson. The only common ancestor of these objects is the java Object. I annotated some of the objects to include type information as a property.

So I create the objects, store them in a map, pass it to a function that serializes the entire collection and then I send the serialized string to a webservice. Pretty simple, but as [the jackson wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) points out, type information is lost due to java type-erasure.

My idea is then to pre-serialize actual objects in the collection (when their actual type is known), and store it some way in the collection to have the entire collection serialized later, using these preserialized strings.
Is this somehow possible? Or is there any workaround that doesn't require the actual types to be known at serialization?

Comment: Have you read about `Externalizable` that will allow you to be able to ovveride the serialize methods, from there you can put in some information about the class to get back the class correctly.

Comment: Any idea on how to use that with jackson?

Comment: Unfortunately no, normally you just implement Externalizable, but with Jackson that might not work

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I created a custom serializer and a custom type:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = PreserializedMapSerializer.class)
class PreserializedMap extends HashMap<String,String>{
}
```

And preserialize the objects:

```
PreserializedMap map = new PreserializedMap();
...
map.put("device",objectMapper.writeValueAsString(device));
```

Then serialize the collection:

```
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map);
```

The serializer is:

```
public static class PreserializedMapSerializer extends JsonSerializer<PreserializedMap>         {

    @Override
    public void serialize(PreserializedMap value, JsonGenerator generator, 
        SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {

        generator.writeStartObject();
        for(Entry<String,String> entry : value.entrySet()){
            generator.writeObjectFieldStart(entry.getKey());
            generator.writeRaw(entry.getValue().substring(1, entry.getValue().length()-1));
            generator.writeEndObject();
        }
        generator.writeEndObject();

    }

}
```